# How to plot multivariate function in R

Tags: r, plot, curve

I am trying to plot the following function:[image]

This is what I have currently tried:

```
curve(7*x*y/( e^(x^2+y^2)))
```

But I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to plot is using the `contour()` function. Also, as @Sang won kim noted, `exp()` is the function for `e^(...)`

```r
x <- seq(from = 0.01, to = 2.1, by = 0.01)
y <- x

multi_var_fx <- function (x, y) {
  7 * x * y / (exp(x^2 + y^2))
}

z <- outer(x, y, multi_var_fx)

contour(x, y, z, xlab = 'x', ylab = 'y')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-10-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Your e means exponential function. In the r, exponential function code is `exp()`. So you can revise this code.

```
curve(7*x*y/(exp(x^2+y^2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a contour plot like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(x = seq(0, 10, 0.1),             # define the drawing grid
       y = seq(0, 10, 0.1)
  ) %>% 
cross_df() %>%                          # create all possible combinations of x and y
mutate(z = 7*x*y/(exp(x^2+y^2)) ) %>%   # add your function
ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, z = z)) +      # create the plot
  geom_contour()
```

[image: contour plot]